# Need to copy custom vm image from one subscription to another subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, migration, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Problem statement:
I would like to know, if there is an option to copy the image from one subscription to another subscription.

Usecase:
I have a custom vm image in a subscription, I would like to use this image to create a vm in different subscription.

Resolution:
Please help me here

Comment: Questions about Azure management operations are off-topic, if there isn't a programming issue. Try ServerFault or SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps can help out

1. Create a [shared Image Gallery](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2Fgalleries) in your subscription which has the custom Image
2. You can replicate the image versions in the gallery to other regions or copy an image from another gallery using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/image-version-another-gallery-cli) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/image-version-another-gallery-powershell).

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to shared image gallery, but do have any other option to just replicate the image.I could see option to move image from one subscription to another, but cant we replicate ?

Comment: You can't replicate as Microsoft Q&A says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries#can-i-replicate-my-image-versions-across-subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for the response, very helpful.Any other better site to post queries related to Azure .